# Merge String with a date in excel 2003

Tags: excel

How to merge  a string with a date  in *excel 2003*, =A1&" "&TEXT(B1,"m/dd/yyyy")   not working in 2003  but working in 2007. Asuming "A1" As a string and "B1" as  a date"

Comment: Try `=A1&TEXT(B1, " m/dd/yyyy; @")`.

Comment: Hi, Jeeped , It is giving output   as  Hi 0/dd/yyyy   Note: A1=Hi

Comment: What language is the Excel 2003 running under? I recently had to help an FI-FI (Finish) user use a date format mask that was not m, d or y.

Comment: The server  is in Germany where  i am running  my excel  so the language  is DE( dutch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using format masks and they are not working out, the first thing to check is the language pack that the Office installation is running under. Your best estimate is DE-DE. This is important to know; particularly when sourcing and localizing a problem.

I've just checked the translated [Custom Number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) for DE-DE at [Erstellen oder Löschen eines benutzerdefinierten Zahlenformats](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/Erstellen-oder-L%C3%B6schen-eines-benutzerdefinierten-Zahlenformats-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=de-DE&rs=de-DE&ad=DE) and apparently an M is still an M but a D should be a T and Y is J.

Try this formatting mask. Note that I've included the space in the format mask itself.

```
=A1&TEXT(B1," m/tt/jjjj")
```

If that is still not producing the correct results, you will have to dig a little deeper into the machine configuration and determine the Office system language definitively.

[TEXT funktion](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/TEXT-Funktion-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945?ui=fi-FI&rs=de-DE&ad=FI)